# How can i include a block in wishlist page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, wishlist

I want to add a block in wishlist layout.

```
<block class="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="Magento_ConfigurableProduct::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml"/>
```

I added it in wishlist_index_index.xml file but it's not displaying.

[image]

I want it below the price. 
I want it to appear like this.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to block only for configurable products ?

Comment: Yes. On Wishlist page

Comment: which content do you want to show and where ? could you please share with me screenshots

Comment: Updated my question just check.

Comment: You should customization in wishlist page. override file not work there.

Comment: So it's no point in adding new Block in the layout. What if i create a customized block and inheret the Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable and respective phtml file?

Comment: No, I have tried but it's not working.

Comment: So any alternative ?